# FPC Connector - Matebook X Pro

Tags: laptop, ribbon-cable, fpc

Please excuse me if this is not the right place to ask this question.

I have been looking for a specific ribbon cable (motherboard to LCD board) for my **Huawei Matebook X Pro** for more than a year now and I still can't find it.

Now, Im trying to see if someone with good soldering skills and have proper tools would be able to just replace the FPC connector and so I'm looking for this FPC connector below, you can see on the screenshot seem to have 3 broken PINS

[image]

[image]

I've spent countless hours searching online for this but Im still not sure if its even possible for me to know which one to get. I check on digikey and the result is just overwhelming.

All I know is it has 40 pins, but Im not sure if all the FPC which looks like this and has 40 pins would fit on this. I've seen FPC connector for Smartphones on AliExpress with 40 pins on them which looks like this but I have no idea if they are the same and can be use on my case.

BTW, here is the actual image of the flex connector that I can't find online
[image]
[image]

I'd appreciate if someone can advise how to get that correct FPC connector.

Cheers.

Comment: You might have some luck with SAMTEC. They make that sort of thing. You'll need to measure the connector carefully though, often times these parts are customized to fit the application. It may not have an off-the-shelf part

Comment: I /think/ I've seen this exact connector, it is usually used for connecting eDP through a flat flex PCB to a panel. Search for mezzanine connectors, and you're gonna have a bad time finding the entire assembly unless you search ebay.

Comment: @Symmetrics, please take the repair part of the question out of your post. Repair questions are off topic. We do identification questions, but you will need to provide adequate measurements (pitch of solder pads and dimensions of the connector). If editing doesn't work for you, I will be forced to close the question

Comment: For a forum that allows the repair part of your question you could look at www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist and join the mailing list and say hello. You can refer to this question with [this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/511012/3288)

Answer (score 1):

Reminds the Molex slimstack. Can be similar enough to order samples. Can you check the pitch?

https://www.molex.com/molex/search/deepSearch?pQuery=productname%253A%2522SlimStack%2522%2540pitchmatinginterface%253A%25220.40mm%2522

Answer (score 0):

These look like a variant of the Panasonic FPC to board connectors.

If you can take measurements and have a close look at the details [here](https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/eu/board-to-board-board-to-fpc.htm) you might be able to figure out which exact model it is.

I haven't had many successes with repairing FPCs (they were delaminating quite fast), but you might have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.zandparts.com/en/Huawei-03024UXB

This may be your part. I'd search this site. Unfortunately there are no images to compare to but the part is cheap so it wouldn't hurt to just grab one.